# Can you check my working on some basic algebra questions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please could you check my answers for me, I'm doing a Maths GCSE and would like someone to validate my answers;

1) $-2a*-2a=4a$,

2) $-3a*2a=-6a$

3) $\frac{-2a}{-2a}= a$

4) $\frac{-2a}{2a}= -a$

5) $-2a + -2a=-4a$

6) $-3a*-3a=0$

7)$-3a^2 -4a^2=4a$

8)$-3a^2 --3a^2=4a$

9)$-3a^2 *-3a^2=4a$

10)$\frac{-3a^2}{-3a^2} =4a$

11)$\sqrt3a*\sqrt3a=3a$

12)$\frac{\sqrt3a}{\sqrt3a}=a$

Comment: 13) What have you tried yourself? Can you say why your answer in 10) is $4a$?

Comment: -2a * -2a = 4a? what?

Comment: @mathfan27543 The first five are not all correct, assuming asterix means multiplication.

Comment: I think #4 is right, the rest look wrong to me.

Comment: only the fifth one is correct.

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant #5 is correct and the rest are wrong.

Comment: A GCSE student (under 16 y/o) is asking a question here. They may or may not know about the house rules. The severe down-grade is totally unnecessary.

Comment: For 3, what is $\frac{x}{x}$?  Set $x = -2a$ and now try again.  To be exact, you should comment that it is only valid if $a \neq 0$.

Comment: I've added an answer below, but it would be really beneficial for you to explain to us how you got the answers you did, as there is clearly some fundamental misunderstanding you have with this type of question and we may be able to help you out even more than the vague help we are able to give right now

Comment: Thank you Bacon, I am probably at KS3 level.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $*$ means 'multiply, then for $(1)$
\begin{align}
-2a \times -2a &= -2 \times -2 \times a \times a \\
&= 4 \times a \times a \\
&= 4 \times a^{2} \\
&= 4a^2
\end{align}
Also, for (3) - ignore the factor of $a$ for a second, ask your self what is 
$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}$$
equal to?

Read as 'how may one-halfs are there in one-half?' - the answer is $1$, right? What about
$$\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{3}}?$$
Again, how many one-thirds are there in one-third? Again, the answer is $1$. What about
$$\frac{\frac{1}{2} \times 2}{\frac{1}{2}\times 2}?$$
Well, this is clearly equal to $1$ too.

What about $$\frac{\frac{1}{2} \times a}{\frac{1}{2} \times a}?$$
Where $a$ can be 'any real number'. Once again, surprise, surprise, the answer is $1$.

Some of you answers above are correct, and I bet you know which ones. For those like the two above, just try those again.

Comment: So, I've followed you guidance and have the following answers for the questions;
$ 1) 4a^2,   2) 6a^2,   3) 1,   4), -4a,   5) 1,   6) -6a^2, 7) -7a^2,   8)-6a^2,   9)9a^2,  10)1,   11)\sqrt {9a^2},   12)1$

Comment: @WillJ -  great effort Will. Check your answers to $(4)$ and $(5)$ - I think you have them the wrong way around and be careful of the -ve sign! Also in $(8)$ you have the negative of a subtraction which is the same as..what? In $(9)$ remember to use laws of indices so that $a^{2} \times a^{2}=a^{k}$ where $k= \ldots$? In $(11)$ can you simplify $\sqrt{9} \times \sqrt{a^{2}}$?

Comment: Sorry this is taking so long; $(4)$ and $(5)$ I'm not sure what I've done wrong, please can you explain?
With $(8)$, is this $6a^2$? If so, can you explain why the square does not minus or add?
With $(9)$, is this $9a^4$?
Is $(11)$, $\sqrt{9^2}$ ?

Comment: @WillJ No problem Will, it's important for you to check answers and you are asking the right questions. With $(11)$, you have $a \sqrt{9} \times a\sqrt{9} = a \times a \times (\sqrt{9})^2 = \ldots$? With $(8)$ the 'like' term is $3a^{2}$ and you are subtracting the negative of this from the negative of this. Meaning it's the same as adding the like term to the negative of itself...meaning zero! With $(4),(5)$, you have effectively "a thing"/"same thing" giving $1$, can you see why that is?

Answer (score 2):

First off, answering your question "could you check my answers for me", I will say whether each is correct or not.

1. Incorect
2. Incorrect
3. Incorrect
4. Incorrect
5. Correct
6. Incorrect
7. Incorrect
8. Incorrect
9. Incorrect
10. Incorrect
11. Incorrect, unless the question was actually $\sqrt{3a}*\sqrt{3a}$
12. Incorrect

---

Now for how to correct the incorrect answers.

Read Bacon's answer on dealing with fractions. Another way of thinking about this kind of question would be, for a question such as $\frac {2a}{2a}$, to say "I need to divide $2a$ apples into $2a$ equal piles, how many apples will I have in each pile?" The answer will always be $1$, if you have the same number on the top of the fraction as you do on the bottom. You may also want to use the fact that we can write the negative sign in fractions in many ways; these are all equal:

$$\frac{-2a}{3a}=-\frac{2a}{3a}=\frac{2a}{-3a}$$

Can you use this to correct questions $3$, $4$, $10$, and $12$?

Now, consider question $1$:

We have \begin{align}-2a*-2a &= -2*a*-2*a\\&=4*a*a\\&=4*a^2\\&=4a^2\end{align} Can you see where this came from, and use it to correct questions $2$, $6$, $9$, and $11$?

Finally, consider question $7$:

We have \begin{align}-3a^2-4a^2 &= (-3-4)*a^2 \\&= -7a^2\end{align} Can you see where this came from and use it to correct question $8$?